# Access object inside array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object and I want to access the value of types as a property to another object like a.Fax, a.Email, a.Call etc. But I have written a function down below and it pushes the values to a.ttt. So instead of ttt I want to access each value inside types i.e Fax, Email, Call, Text which is stored in ttt.

```
export const ActionTypes2 = [
    { value: "OtherLawyer", label: "Other Lawyer", types: ["Fax", "Email", "Call", "Text"] },
    { value: "OtherClerk", label: "Other Clerk", types: ["Fax", "Email", "Call", "Text"]  },
    { value: "BrokerageAgent", label: "Brokerage Agent", types: ["Fax", "Email", "Call", "Text"]  },
    { value: "Lawyer", label: "Lawyer", types: ["Email", "Call", "Text"]  },
    { value: "Clerk", label: "Clerk", types: ["Email", "Call", "Text"] },
    { value: "Client", label: "Client", types: ["Email", "Call", "Text"] },
    { value: "ListingAgent", label: "Listing Agent", types: ["Email", "Call", "Text"] },
    { value: "CooperatingAgent", label: "Cooperating Agent", types: ["Email", "Call", "Text"] }
]


getActionTypes() {
    let t = ActionTypes2;
    let f = <any>{};
    t.map((tt: any) => {
      tt.types.map((ttt: any) => {
        if (!f.ttt) {
          f.ttt = [];
        }
        f.ttt.push(t);
        // console.log(ttt);
      })
    })
    console.log(f);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide example result array

Comment: Your code should already work but you need `if (!f[ttt]) `, `f[ttt] = [];` and `f[ttt].push(t);`. I would also advice to not use map but forEach, map is used to return a new array and usually does not mutate something or use reduce as in my answer as that's used to return a new value from an array of values (like sum an array of numbers).

Answer (score 0):

How about below,

```
getActionTypes() {
   let t = ActionTypes2;
   let f = <any>{};
   t.map((tt: any) => {
     if (!f.ttt) {
       f.ttt = [];
     }
     f.ttt.push(tt.types);
   })
   console.log(f.ttt);  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace f.ttt with f[ttt] as follows

```
getActionTypes() {
    let t = ActionTypes2;
    let f = <any>{};
    t.map((tt: any) => {
        tt.types.map((ttt: any) => {
            if (!f[ttt]) {
                f[ttt] = [];
            }
            f[ttt].push(t);
            // console.log(ttt);
        })
    })
    console.log(f);
}
```

Comment: Method passed to map should be a pure function, if you mutate or use something defined outside of the function you should probably use forEach instead. However; this could be more easily accomplished using reduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to an object (note that SO prints the console a bit strange, press F12 and check out the console for the actual result):

```js
const data = [{"value":"OtherLawyer","label":"Other Lawyer","types":["Fax","Email","Call","Text"]},{"value":"OtherClerk","label":"Other Clerk","types":["Fax","Email","Call","Text"]},{"value":"BrokerageAgent","label":"Brokerage Agent","types":["Fax","Email","Call","Text"]},{"value":"Lawyer","label":"Lawyer","types":["Email","Call","Text"]},{"value":"Clerk","label":"Clerk","types":["Email","Call","Text"]},{"value":"Client","label":"Client","types":["Email","Call","Text"]},{"value":"ListingAgent","label":"Listing Agent","types":["Email","Call","Text"]},{"value":"CooperatingAgent","label":"Cooperating Agent","types":["Email","Call","Text"]}];

const groupByType = (data) =>
  data.reduce(
    (result, { types, ...rest }) =>
      types.reduce((result, type) => {
        result[type] = result[type] || [];
        result[type].push(rest);
        return result;
      }, result),
    {},
  );
console.log(groupByType(data));
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to convert an array of 'T to an array of 'U or even produce a new array of the same type but doubled (for example `[1,2,3].map(x=>x*2)`). The function passed to map should be a pure function so it should not use or mutate something defined outside the function or change the array being mapped.